# Consultancy Company vs Getting Hired By Client

Tags: job-offer, united-states, new-job

Suppose a person works for a business consulting company for a client company and that client company offers him a full time position.

In most cases, would it be best just to take the offer from the client company rather than hoping that your contract gets extended?

Comment: whats the location? This will influence the answer

Comment: @Benjamin: Both companies are in the USA.

Comment: This highly depends on the terms of your contract, and likely the contract between the client company and the consulting company. Usually you can't just switch to clients (nor is the client allowed to just offer you a contract without some compensation to the consulting company). At least, that was my experience a decade or so ago in the Netherlands.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel they are not offering me a "contract".....they are offering me a full-time job. How is it different from some applying to a job at a company and getting accepted?

Comment: @user21478 usually employment is cemented with a contract. Are you sure you want to take a job without contract? They can easily back down after you resigned from your job.

Comment: @user21478 Maybe it works differently in the US, but were I come from, a job comes with a contract that includes things like your starting salary, the duration of the contract (e.g one year + terms of extension, or permanent), probation period, the hours you work, and other terms governing your working relationship with your employer.

Comment: I think it would depend on what your current contract is.  It may prohibit you from working for their client, or in teh same industry etc

Comment: What do you mean "they are not offering me a "contract".....they are offering me a full-time job"?  In order to offer you a full time job they have to offer you a contract.

Comment: In our part of the world, there is an explicit and individual employment contract for fulltime jobs.  Don't you sign any agreement/paperwork?  That is the contract !

Comment: In the US, in the vast majority of cases there is not an employment contract for what we call a “permanent full time employee.” You get a short job offer letter with position and salary, you accept it, and you are hired.  You have to sign a tax form and usually some other specific legal document(s) like NDA, IP rights, etc. but not an employment contract with a term of time.  Employment in most places is “permanent” but “at will,” you can quit or be fired at any time and there is no time your employment expires. We call term-based workers “contractors” because they, you know, have a contract.

Answer (score 5):

There are two contracts/agreements you have to worry about. One you of them you are directly a party to and the other you weren't.

The one that is easiest to find is the one between you and your employer. They may try to prevent you from being hired by one of their clients. The company doesn't want to turn into a hiring agency for their clients. Though some companies are fine with this.

The other one is between the company and the client. That contract may forbid poaching of employees. You probably have never seen all of the contract. It is even possible that the person trying to get you hasn't read the contract. I have seen these types of contracts say that there has to be a gap of x months since you left the contract before they can hire you. That can be fulfilled by unemployment, being on a different contract, or working for another company.

Ignoring all of that, and assuming just the question you asked:

> In most cases, would it be best just to take the offer from the client
> company rather than hoping that your contract gets extended?

There are several things that you have to evaluate:

- Which one would offer more stable employment?
- Which one has the better potential growth?
- Which has the more interesting work?
- Pay, benefits, and work location can't be ignored.

In other words the decision is exactly the same that everybody else has to make. It is based on your current work situation, and your guess for the future.

Comment: Should I ask for the salary first and then give my current  salary to negotiate? Or should I even try and tell my current company that I have a potential offer from another company with a higher  salary and see if they can match it?

Comment: There are other questions on this site regarding getting a counter offer. But you don't want to give a reason to anger your current company before you even know if you can take the new job or even want the new job.

Answer (score 1):

> In most cases, would it be best just to take the offer from the client
> company rather than hoping that your contract gets extended?

As always, it depends.

- It depends on your interest in working full time for this client company
- It depends on the specifics of the offer compared to what you are getting now
- It depends on if your contract with the consultancy allows you do leave and go work for the client company

Comment: Any advice on how to negotiate for a higher salary?

Answer (score -1):

You should consider your contract, check it for clauses, leaving a consultancy company for customer you were introduced by company.
If no such thing exist, you free and clear to evaluate conditions (salary / benefits etc.) and make your employment decision.
Some may say, you have moral obligation and such, but, imho, it is not. Your salary probably is around 30% of the amounts paid by the customer

If clause exist, it is very dependent on the wording and your location.

I am not a lawyer, you may want to consult employment one :)

As an individual, you have basic right to work where and for whom you choose.
Too broad, restrictive or time-limiting clause can be considered null and void as infringing on that right

Thank you for downvote without comment, shows that it was read and someone see it as danger to their profit margin :)